# How to find content that uses a File (File Entity)?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, files

Want to be able to see what content has file field(s) that refer to a specific file.

Is this do-able using a View (with Relationships)? (had a go already, unsuccessful so far).
Alternatively I'd query database tables (via the proper API) and relate that way, but just thought I'd ask if there is a generic solution before potentially re-inventing the wheel.

Searched a lot butn get a lot of unrelated search results. Search engine cannot seem to be told that I want my terms ordered in a certain way.

Ultimately I'd like to have a View that shows the Files and the content that uses each file. I would then be able to see the impact of deleting a file for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a view of type files:
[image: Creating a view of type files]

Add a relationship to 'Content', make sure you set it as required:
[image: Relationship to content]

Add any fields you wish to see of the file or the node.

Comment: What about other file types, other than Image? Like .xlsx etc.? Thanks @Maarten De Block so far...

Comment: Ah, there is also a `File: Content using Files` I saw, I'll look into that...

Comment: For every field of type file or image you make, a new relationship will become available. Please mark as answered if this solves your problem.

Comment: +1 upvote, I think this is the solution I am looking for, I'm still looking into it as I would be expecting the View result to show a column with node id after adding this relationship and then adding a `File: Content using Files` field to the Fields. Would this solution work for any content type that has a File field?

Comment: You need to add fields, this could be nid, or any other field of the node or file. And this wil indeed work for every content type with a file field.

Comment: I found this to work: that adding `File Usage: Content` to the `Relationships` (on the right hand side of the View edit screen and then adding a field: `(Content) Content: Title` to the `Fields` section (on the left). I'd like to accept your answer - could you update your answer with my finding?